# Top border of table is not drawn

Tags: tables, beamer, border

I built a table using [www.tablesgenerator.com](http://www.tablesgenerator.com), selecting that all borders must be added. However, when I insert the code and compile it, the top border is not properly drawn (see in Figure):

[image]

Here is the simplified version of my .tex file:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, xcolor=table,envcountsect]{beamer}[trans]
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,comment}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
        
\begin{table}[htb!]
\centering
\resizebox{9cm}{!}{
\label{prediccion}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|}
\cline{2-4}
                                                                           & \cellcolor[HTML]{CBCEFB}Valor predicho & \cellcolor[HTML]{CBCEFB}Valor experimental & \cellcolor[HTML]{CBCEFB}{\color[HTML]{000000} $R^2   $} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFE65}\% Proteína Extraída}         & 23.03                &      20.23                    & 0.95                                                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFE65}\% Carbohidratos Extraídos}   & 64.48                            & -              & 0.98                                                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFE65}Ratio Proteína/Carbohidratos} & 0.43                                  & -         & 0.62                                                 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: see `texdoc colortbl` that is a documented restriction that you can not use `\cline` with coloured panels. If that is being generated it should be reported as a bug in the generator.

Comment: And is there no other way to create that table without \cline?

Comment: as documented, you could use `\hhline` but I would remove all the horizontal and vertical lines: they do not aid reading the table, and together with coloured panels make it all look very "cluttered"

Comment: @DavidMoldes You might want to have a look at https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf

Comment: @DavidMoldes You might also want to have a look at the `siunitx` package to get your numbers aligned.

Comment: @DavidMoldes Using `\resizebox` for content which contains text usually gives a poor result. Better choose a suitable fontsize to fit your table on the frame. You also don't need to load the `graphicx` and `xcolor` packages, beamer does this for you.

Comment: @DavidMoldes Beamer also does not have a floating mechanism, so specifying `[htb!]` as floating specifier does not make much sense. Beamer also has its own column mechanism, better use this instead of the `multicols` package.

Comment: @DavidMoldes ... also not sure what you think the `[trans]` option *after* the beamer class is supposed to do.

Answer (score 4):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, envcountsect]{beamer}[trans]
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
        
\begin{center}
\label{prediccion}
\small
\begin{NiceTabular}{cScS}[corners=NW,hvlines,cell-space-limits=2pt]
\CodeBefore
  \columncolor[HTML]{FFFE65}{1}
  \rowcolor[HTML]{CBCEFB}{1}
\Body
 & {Valor predicho} & Valor experimental & {$R^2$} \\ 
\% Proteína Extraída         & 23.03 & 20.23 & 0.95 \\ 
\% Carbohidratos Extraídos   & 64.48 & -     & 0.98 \\ 
Ratio Proteína/Carbohidratos & 0.43  & -     & 0.62 \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]